# What happened to the Muggleborns 11 and under in 1997?

Tags: harry-potter

Given that during that year both the Ministry and Hogwarts were under control of the Death Eaters and pursuing virulently anti-Muggleborn policies, what were the repercussions for the Muggleborns who were at that point too young to attend Hogwarts, but whose names would have already been written by the magic quill in Hogwarts, and hence in the hands of the Death Eaters running the show?

Specifically, what happened to those too young to receive letters or know about magic/Hogwarts in 1997? And what about those who were supposed to be attending first year that year?

Answer (score 19):

I don't know if JKR has ever mentioned it or not. But here is some info from the canon:

> “Attendance is now compulsory for every young witch and wizard,” he replied.
> “That was announced yesterday. It’s a change, because it was never obligatory before. Of course, nearly every witch and wizard in Britain has been educated at Hogwarts, but their parents had the right to teach them at home or send them abroad if they preferred. This way, Voldemort will have the whole Wizarding population under his eye from a young age. And it’s also another way of weeding out Muggle-borns, because  students must be
> given Blood Status – meaning that they have proven to the Ministry that they are of Wizard descent – before they are allowed to attend.”
>
> Harry felt sickened and angry: at this moment excited eleven-year-olds would be poring over stacks of newly purchased spellbooks, unware that they would never see Hogwarts, **perhaps never see their families again either.**
>
> <sub>"The Bribe" - *The Deathly Hallows* (Emphasis mine)</sub>

So we weren't explicitly told what would happen to them. We were just told that Harry felt angry about what was going to happen to these excited young children.

However, we can guess a bit. Note that there is no difference between a grown-up Muggle-born and an eleven-year-old Muggle-born. The following is an extract from the same chapter:

> ".... said Lupin. “Nevertheless, unless you can prove that you have at least one close Wizarding relative, you are now deemed to have obtained your magical power illegally and must suffer the punishment.”

These Muggle-borns were not killed. Therefore there can't be a reason the eleven-year-olds have to be killed as well. So if they were not killed, and the worst that could have happened to them was that they were sentenced to Azkaban, then we can say/guess that in the year ensuing  Voldemort's death, they were once again invited to Hogwarts (I don't believe parents would want their children to go to Hogwarts after an year of not seeing them).

Again, this is just speculation.

Answer (score 10):

To the best of my knowledge, this has not been addressed in any of the books or in any published interview or writing by JKR.

That said, I expect the answer is 'nothing'.  The Ministry and the Hogwarts Governors had their hands full with consolidating power, stamping out resistance, and otherwise reshaping the wizarding world.  They likely had no time or resources to spare 'dealing' with a handful of eleven-year-olds.

I would guess (supported by no canon evidence, only inference) that they were simply ignored.  They received neither letters nor visits from Professors, and went about their Muggle education.  Most likely, they were invited to Hogwarts the next year (or over the summer holiday), and joined Hogwarts as normal.

Comment: I lean towards "murdered by Death-Eaters". They don't seem to like muggleborn wizards very much.

Comment: @Richard: That seems a bit too dark for JKR.  Also, I'd expect that widespread murder of children, if it became known, would have caused more resistance to Death Eaters than simply not inviting Muggleborns to magical schools.

Comment: @Jeff, the darkness might be the reason why JKR did not mention anything in the books.There is actually one line in the seventh book where this topic is mentioned.I can't find the line but it went something like this:"...or of those muggleborns who were excited to use their new wands,not knowing they would never goto Hogwarts."

Comment: Found the exact sentence:"Harry felt sickened and angry:at this moment excited eleven year olds would be poring over stacks of newly purchased spellbooks,unware that they would never see Hogwarts,perhaps never see their families again either."

Comment: Wait,Dumbledore wanted Snape to become the Headmaster.He might have played a role in their safety.

Comment: @Jeff I don't think Voldemort was the sort of person who would temper his beliefs/actions due to consideration of what others would think; even if it would be in his best interest. If we compare him to Hitler (a comparison which has been made numerous times) who conducted the holocaust, even though it would have harmed many possible alliances. People who feel they are on a mission tend not to compromise.

Comment: Another reason for this to have been the case is that Voldemort does not care about those he does not perceive as threats, as Dumbledore has said many times. He would not think of the 11-year-olds as threats (yet), and therefore they would be safe from his Inquisition, for now. You can counter that he tried to kill Harry as a baby, but first of all, he did not think of Harry as a threat yet, and therefore did not take necessary precautions, and secondly, Harry wasn't a present threat but he was a *future* threat, which even Voldemort is smart enough to acknowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> Harry felt sickened and angry: At this moment, excited eleven-year-olds would be poring over stacks of newly purchased spell-books, unaware that they would never see Hogwarts, perhaps never see their families again either.

These are students who are first year rising who already have their tickets and their wands. In all likelihood, Harry was correct. And since when had the busy matters of a new government takeover stopped bigots and racists from taking time out to impose their hate. The cruelty wasn't an inadvertent result of their policies, the cruelty was the point of the policies.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   This quote was noted in one of the other answers (it would be better if you attributed it, actually) but it doesn't say what _would_ happen to them, just what wouldn't.  Is there anything else that better answers the question?